# how can I use callfromthread to call a method of a protocol in twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I have a twisted web socket client protocol and I have another socket server in this reactor loop
how can I access to sendMessage method from socket server?
I see this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autobahnws/Z96freyvIF0) but I didn't get what should I do. I try this but I get some error:

```
reactor.callFromThread(WebSocketClientProtocol.sendMessage, protocol,  'data')
exceptions.TypeError: unbound method sendMessage() must be called with WebSocketClientProtocol instance as first argument (got module instance instead)
```

my websocket client:

```
class WebSocketProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):


   def sendHello(self):
      self.sendMessage("something")

   def onOpen(self):
      self.sendHello()

   def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
      print msg

websocket_factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://localhost:1025/ws")
websocket_factory.protocol = WebSocketProtocol
connectWS(websocket_factory)
```

I solve It by this code:

```
class WebSocketProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):


   def onOpen(self):
        self.factory.data = []
        self.factory.data.append(self)

reactor.callFromThread(WebSocketClientProtocol.sendMessage, websocket_factory.data[0],  send)
```

Answer (score 4):

`callFromThread` is only for use when you have multiple *threads* in your program.  Just because you have multiple servers doesn't mean you have multiple threads.  In fact, Twisted is largely oriented towards running multiple servers (and/or clients) without using any extra threads.

The specific error you've encountered is about how you need to call an *instance method* on an *instance*, though.

`WebSocketClientProtocol` is a class and `WebSocketClientProtocol.sendMessage` is an unbound method.  This is like trying to write:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print "Foo.bar:", self

Foo.bar()
```

This doesn't work any better than what you tried because of course you need to have an instance:

```
foo = Foo()
...
foo.bar()
```

Comment: so how should I call that? I mean what is the twisted way ?

Comment: You could use a factory derived from `WebSocketClientFactory` that remembers the protocol instance it creates (in `buildProtocol`). This reference can then be used to provide the *instance* parameter you need for use with `callFromThread` (assuming the factory is reachable from where you want to trigger the `sendMessage`).